# Copy file to dict with ast.literal_eval without memory leak

Tags: python

I am trying to do a "file to dict" conversion where each line of the file is a literal representation of a dict and I want to store each dict in a dict that references them by line number.

I thought it would be pretty straighforward but it seems like `ast.literal_eval` is somehow producing memory leaks or that something is not garbage collected.

Here is a simple directly runnable way to reproduce the issue:

```
import sys, os
from guppy import hpy
import ast

print("creating the file, each line is a python dict")
line="{'foo1':'bar1','foo2':'bar2','foo3':'bar3','foo4':'bar4','foo5':'bar5'}"
with open('each_line_is_a_python_dict.txt', 'w+') as file:
  for i in range(10000000):
    file.write('%s\n' % line)
    
print("the size of the file is", os.path.getsize("each_line_is_a_python_dict.txt")/1024/1024, "MB")
print("heap after creating the file: ")
h = hpy()
print(h.heap())

dict_of_dicts = {}
with open("each_line_is_a_python_dict.txt") as f:
  for lineno,line in enumerate(f):
    dict_of_dicts[lineno] = ast.literal_eval(line)
    
print("sys.getsizeof(dict_of_dicts)", sys.getsizeof(dict_of_dicts))
print("heap after creating the dict_of_dicts:")
h = hpy()
print(h.heap())
```

Here is the output I get (running with pipenv on Windows 10 PowerShell):

```
creating the file, each line is a python dict                         
the size of the file is 696.1822509765625 MB                          
heap after creating the file:                                         
Partition of a set of 40632 objects. Total size = 5515099 bytes.      
Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of
class)                                                                
0  12414  31  1093030  20   1093030  20 str                           
1   2786   7  1002680  18   2095710  38 types.CodeType                
2    615   2   620872  11   2716582  49 type                          
3   7811  19   554720  10   3271302  59 tuple                         
4   5164  13   464836   8   3736138  68 bytes                         
5   2541   6   386232   7   4122370  75 function                      
6    615   2   222264   4   4344634  79 dict of type                  
7     98   0   128704   2   4473338  81 dict of module                
8    439   1   126936   2   4600274  83 dict (no owner)               
9   1203   3    86616   2   4686890  85 types.WrapperDescriptorType   
<145 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>                         
sys.getsizeof(dict_of_dicts) 335544400                                
heap after creating the dict_of_dicts:                                
Partition of a set of 70040311 objects. Total size = 5111046479 bytes.
Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of
class)                                                                
0 50012416  71 2651093206  52 2651093206  52 str                      
1 10000421  14 2175667080  43 4826760286  94 dict (no owner)          
2 10001078  14 280033684   5 5106793970 100 int                       
3   2786   0  1002680   0 5107796650 100 types.CodeType               
4    615   0   620872   0 5108417522 100 type                         
5   7811   0   554720   0 5108972242 100 tuple                        
6   5164   0   464836   0 5109437078 100 bytes                        
7   2541   0   386232   0 5109823310 100 function                     
8    615   0   222264   0 5110045574 100 dict of type                 
9     98   0   128704   0 5110174278 100 dict of module               
<145 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

Meanwhile, the memory use rises constantly, to values that far exceed the size of the file, here even 10GB:

[image]

Is it an issue with `ast.literal_eval` or is something else wrong?

Comment: I simplified your code to `for lineno in range(10000000):
   dict_of_dicts[lineno] = ast.literal_eval(line)` and that displays the same issue, i.e., 71% strings and a large memory footprint.

Comment: If anything, this is using *less* memory than I would expect. There should have been another 50 million strings there - I don't think the implementation tries to intern any of those strings, and the compiler doesn't get a chance to perform any constant merging.

Comment: What Python implementation/version did you use?

Comment: @KellyBundy Python 3.11.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation this does not seem to be related to `ast.literal_eval`. Each dictionary contains five strings, and these need to be stored in memory. Therefore the amount of strings is five times the amount of dictionaries.

See the following simplified code:

```
from guppy import hpy
import random, string

# random string of 5 letters and numbers
def rndstr():
   return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=5))

dict_of_dicts = {}
for lineno in range(5000000):
   dict_of_dicts[lineno] = {'foo1':rndstr(),'foo2':rndstr(),'foo3':rndstr(),'foo4':rndstr(),'foo5':rndstr()}

print("heap after creating the dict_of_dicts:")
h = hpy()
print(h.heap())
```

Output:

```
heap after creating the dict_of_dicts:
Partition of a set of 35085605 objects. Total size = 2828147435 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0 25028993  71 1352598706  48 1352598706  48 str
     1 5000812  14 1328234952  47 2680833658  95 dict (no owner)
     2 5002324  14 140071024   5 2820904682 100 int
     3  18966   0  1354624   0 2822259306 100 tuple
     4   5858   0  1035905   0 2823295211 100 types.CodeType
     5   1094   0   997800   0 2824293011 100 type
     6   9590   0   812494   0 2825105505 100 bytes
     7   5480   0   789120   0 2825894625 100 function
     8   1094   0   529288   0 2826423913 100 dict of type
     9    218   0   405072   0 2826828985 100 dict of module
<250 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

The process (note that only 5M dictionaries are created) uses a maximum of 4.2GB memory. Note also that 5M ints are stored in memory for the top-level dictionary keys.

Comment: "Each dictionary contains five strings, and these need to be stored in memory." - looks to me like they should each have 10. I'm not sure what's happening to the rest. (In your code, the foo strings are hardcoded into the source code, so the same constant strings get reused every time the expressions are evaluated, but that shouldn't happen with the code in the question.)

Comment: reproduced the same results with your code. very nice reduction of problem scope ! It seems strange that creating such a small and simple dict of dict would unavoidably result in such a massive memory use. How would you proceed to create the same dict with a reasonable memory footprint ?

Comment: @shrimpdrake the large memory use is because you have 10 million of them :) depending on how regular the dictionaries are (do they always have the same number of keys, are the keys always the same strings, what kind of insertion and lookup operations are you planning to do with them after they are loaded) you could look at different data structures such as lists or maybe objects with slots (see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots). Or look at some (possibly in-memory) database solutions.

Comment: @user2357112 for some reason guppy.hpy doesn't count dictionary keys if they are strings (it does count them for, e.g., integer or float keys). I don't know if that is a bug in hpy or if Python does something special that hides them. It doesn't have to do with constants or reusing, for example `for i in range(10000): d[str(i)] = i` gives 10000 ints and zero strings.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it pinpoints the "issue" and explains why this is "normal" behavior. Interesting points made by user2357112, Marjin and Kelly Bundy about the oddities of guppy there.

Comment: @Marijn: Probably has something to do with how if a dict has only ever had string keys, it doesn't report the key references to the GC. If heapy is relying on GC APIs to find objects, it won't find the keys.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't think dicts report *any* objects to GC other than themselves. Objects generally report themselves, no? And I think strings never do (why would they?).

Comment: @KellyBundy: Objects report references they own to the GC, so the GC can do its job, but they can leave out any references that are guaranteed not to participate in a reference cycle. (You can see the references they report with `gc.get_referents`.) Dicts have a bunch of special-case handling for if they've only ever had string keys (because that's a very common case), and one part of that special-case handling is [not reporting their key references](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.5/Objects/dictobject.c#L3538-L3550) in that case.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, a different kind of "report" than I thought. Yes, that might very well explain guppy's miscounting (including the "fun" thing mentioned in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Guppy is lying, you have 100 million string objects, not just 50 million. Each has size 53 bytes (its data + metadata), which takes 64 bytes due to memory alignment (object addresses are all multiples of 16). So that's 6.4 GB already just for the string objects. The dicts and ints take some more GB, indeed ~10 GB overall.

Fun: When I replace key `'foo1'` with `1`, Guppy suddenly correctly reports 9 strings per dict instead of 5.